# How can I get the updated HTML code by AJAX with OkHttp

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, okhttp

I'm trying to get the HTML code of a website in an android app. The website updates the HTML with AJAX and I need to get the new code. I am using OkHttp to do so.

Here is the site I am working on: https://www.ytdl.info/get/mp3/ytQ5CYE1VZw/  I want the generated link of the button.

I have tried other library like JSoup but it does not support JavaScript.

```
OkHttpClient ohc = new OkHttpClient();
final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(myUrl).build();
String htmlCode = ohc.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
```

With the previous code I can get the first HTML code but not the updated one.

Comment: @RachelGallen I am trying to get the response of the AJAX request

Comment: after clicking your button on the website URL given, I inspected the source code, and there was no difference, only that the downloaded file was had a name that was not specified in the HTML. So can you clarify what exactly you are looking for? If you only want the href of the link, you can retrieve that easily using JavaScript?

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes, I just want the href of the link but I don't know how to get it as it is not in the initial HTML code. For instance try https://www.ytdl.info/get/mp3 /youtubeVideID/ replacing youtubeVideID with any other id of YT videos. The page will be processing the video and after some time the link will be added.

Comment: You should be able to access the [okhttp  header responses directly](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp#processing-network-responses) using header.response() have you tried accessing the Content-Location, e.g. ``String header = response.header("Content-Location");`` ?

Comment: @RachelGallen If I try and print request.header("Content-Location") y get null

Comment: I am trying this and I get null `ohc.newCall(request).execute().header("Content-Location")`

Comment: Have a look at how to access the header responses in the linked article (under "processing http" section . I'm not free to look at the moment, not for an hour or 2. Will get back.

Comment: @RachelGallen What for should I access the header? What am I suppose to get from it?